# Mixed models basic

Tags: mixed-model

I am learning mixed models and while reading different materials I still have a couple of questions that I could not find answers.

1. If I have 2 or more fixed effects and if the interaction is not significant can I just drop the interaction term and re run the model?
2. If the interaction is significant in LMMs should I follow the same procedure as Anova for multiple comparisons? Similarly for non-significant interaction?
   What is the method for this kind of situation? I saw in different webs people say in LMM do not explain p values? I can’t understand that?

Answer (score 1):

The rationale for various alternatives is not really different in LMM than in ANOVA. I would advise against doing anything (in either LMM or ANOVA) based just on p values. But other people disagree with me.

I'm not sure what "don't explain p values" means. They may be referring to the random effects rather than the fixed ones, but without context, it is hard to tell.